# Pagination with MaterializeCSS

Tags: laravel, materialize

Is anyone using Materializecss for his laravel project ?
I would like to set up pagination, but it doesn't look really good on the view..
how can I jazz it up?

[image]

this is the code

The controller

```
  public function index()
{

    $services=Service::where('flag',1)->paginate(1);
    $categories=Category::all();
    return view('home',compact('services','categories'));
}
```

The blade

```
        <div class="row center-align">
        {{$services->links()}}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on Laravel 7 and Materialize Css 1.0. Assuming Your links is $cases

```
<ul class="pagination">
    {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
    @if ($cases->onFirstPage()) 
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
    @else
    <li class="waves-effect"><a href="{{ $cases->previousPageUrl() }}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
    @endif

    {{-- Page Number Links --}}
    @for($i=1; $i<=$cases->lastPage(); $i++)
        @if($i==$cases->currentPage())
            <li class="active"><a href="?page={{$i}}">{{$i}}</a></li>
        @else
            <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?page={{$i}}">{{$i}}</a></li>
        @endif
    @endfor

    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
    @if ($cases->hasMorePages())
    <li class="waves-effect"><a href="{{ $cases->nextPageUrl() }}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
    @else
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the pagination view. By default it uses Boostrap. Checkout the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view).

Running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` will give you access to the views you can customize in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory.